# Why do I keep getting 'branch is not a function' in React Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I hope you are doing well!

So I my formik validation file, I have the following code:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
import checkout from "./form";

const {
  formField: {
    description,
    daysOfWeek,
    daysOfWeek: { startHour, endHour, dayName, isWorkDay },
  },
} = checkout;

export default [
  Yup.object().shape({
    [description.name]: Yup.string().required(description.requiredMessage),
    daysOfWeek: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        [dayName.name]: Yup.string(),
        [isWorkDay.name]: Yup.bool(),
        [startHour.name]: Yup.date().when(isWorkDay.name, {
          is: true,
          then: Yup.date()
            .typeError(startHour.invalidMsg)
            .required(startHour.requiredMessage),
          otherwise: Yup.date().nullable(),
        }),
        [endHour.name]: Yup.date()
        .when([isWorkDay.name, startHour.name],
           (isWorkDay, startHourValue, schema) =>
          isWorkDay
            ? schema
                .typeError(endHour.invalidMsg)
                .min(startHourValue, endHour.dateDifference)
                .required(endHour.requiredMessage)
            : schema.nullable()
        ),
      })
    ),
  }),
];
```

I tried several variations like doing the when the condition of the `endHour.name` the same as that of `startHour.name` but with `Yup.ref(startHour.name)` and I'm always getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: branch is not a function

Why is this the case? Why is it happening?